# Change or Focus in jQuery? Which event should I use with select dropdown to give a call to jQuery-AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-events

I've one select dropdown control in HTML as follows :

```
<select id="student" name="student" class="form-control"></select>
```

I want to call a jQuery-AJAX function which will add the option values to the above HTML select control.

Following is the code for I've written for it:

```
    $.ajax({
      url : "http://google.com",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      data: {
        'request_type':'ajax', 
        'op':'get_all_students'
      },
      success: function(result, success) { 
        $('#student').html(result);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error is occured");
      }
    });
```

My issue is on which event of HTML select dropdown should I call the above jQuery-AJAX function in order to add the option values dynamically?

Please suggest me the proper way to do this.

Comment: What is the `result` value?

Comment: @IonicăBizău:The result contains an array of students.

Comment: `result` will be a JSON object, you'll need to turn that data into an `<option>`

Comment: @PHPLover Yeps, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on page load is a good option.

```
jQuery(function($) {
   // Ajax call populate select options
   $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
});
```

if it depends on other selected elements, then bind `change` event on first dropdownlist
e.g. nested dropdown list

```
<select id="teacher" name="teacher" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">Teacher 1</option>
    <option value="2">Teacher 2</option>
</select>
<select id="student" name="student" class="form-control"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
   $("#teacher").on('change', function() {
       // Ajax call populate select options
       $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to write the first function you suggested within $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); or outside it?

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {})` is equiv to `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Answer (score 1):

Listen for `change` event on `select` and then create the the dynamic `<option>` elements poulating the `#student` element with them:

```js
var data = {
  1: [{name: "Alice", id: 1}, {name: "Bob", id: 2}],
  2: [{name: "Carol", id: 2}, {name: "Dave", id: 3}]
};

function getStudents() {
  var result = data[$("#school").val()];
  var $options = [];
  $.each(result, function (i, c) {
    var $opt = $("<option>");
  
    $opt.attr({
      value: c.id
    }).text(c.name);
  
    $options.push($opt);
  });

  $("#students").append($options);
}


$("#school").on("change", getStudents);
getStudents();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="school">
  <option value="1">School 1</option>
  <option value="2">School 2</option>
</select>
<select id="students"></select>
```